# Recycler View with images lags a lot

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am fetching data from a local database inside my app. the database has 43 rows so it's not a long list. 
Here is the part in my code where i'm fetching my data:

```
 fun readAllPoets(): ArrayList<Poet> {
        val poetList: ArrayList<Poet> = arrayListOf<Poet>()
        val db = readableDatabase
        val stringQuery = "SELECT * FROM info"
        val cursor: Cursor = db.rawQuery(stringQuery,null)
        var poetid: String
        var faname: String
        var enname: String
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            poetid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_POET_ID))
            faname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_FANAME))
            enname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBPoet.UserEntry.COLUMN_ENNAME))
            poetList.add(Poet(poetid, faname, enname))
        }
        cursor.close()
        return poetList
    }
```

and then in MainActivity I am calling this function:

```
private fun fetchPoets()  {
   poetList =  DBHelper.UsersDBHelper(this).readAllPoets()
    rvPoetList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    poetList.forEach {
        it.imageId = this.baseContext.resIdByName(it.enName.toLowerCase(),"drawable")

    }
    val adapter = PoetListAdapter()
    adapter.setData(poetList)
    rvPoetList.adapter = adapter

}
```

as you can see I am adding the picture resource id to my Poet object. there is no downloading from the internet. everything is local. 
here is my adapter code:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bind(poet: Poet) {
        itemView.poet_title.setText(poet.faName)
        itemView.img_poet.setImageResource(poet.imageId)
    }

}

fun setData(poets: List<Poet>) {
    this.poets = poets
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.single_poet_view, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    poets?.get(position)?.let { poet ->
        holder.bind(poet)
    }

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { v ->
        listener?.onItemClickListener(v, holder.layoutPosition)
    }
}
```

as you can see i am not constantly calling R.id which i know is a costly call and it makes the recycler view lag. 
Even tho everything is local, Images that I'm fetching localy are fairly small (around 150kb each) and I am not calling R.id constantly, it still lags HEAVILY when scrolling. 
So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of jpeg in kb has little connection to it's size in pixels, so 10 kb jpeg can easily be 10_000*10_000 image and OS must allocate appropriate amount of ram to create bitmap. This is costly and takes time.
Also, if you look as [ImageView::setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView?hl=en#setImageResource(int)) docs, you can see a note `This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.`

To overcome the hassle you can simply use image loading library, like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: i used get drawable and it works perfectly now! thanks a lot for your help